# Can't access kafka.serializer.StringDecoder

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have added the sbt packages fro kafka and spark streaming as follow:

```
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.1",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.6.1"
```

however when I wanna use the kafkadirect streams..I cant access it..

```
val topics="CCN_TOPIC,GGSN_TOPIC"
val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> kafkaBrokers)

val messages= org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils[String, String, kafka.serializer.StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
```

The compiler doesn't recognize  kafka.serializer.StringDecoder..

```
 object serializer is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka
```

EDIT:
I tried also

```
 import  _root_.kafka.serializer
```

..but there is no StringDecoder in that..

Comment: where you are calling the `createDirectStream` method from KafkaUtils class?

Answer (score 4):

Please try this: add the file

> kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0.jar

to your project dependency. It should fix your error.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I use the wrong terminology, I am not an expert in dependencies, linking etc. Below method works using HDP 2.4.3.

### 1. Locating the correct Jar

You need to locate the correct Kafka jars on your environment.

The following shell script is useful for creating a general list of all classes in all Jars and dumping them to a file (which can then be searched with egrep when you need to find Jars for specific classes).

I am using HDP so I specified the root directory of the HDP install as the point to search for jars. Your platform jars might be elsewhere.

```
all_hdp_classes () {
  find -L /usr/hdp/current -maxdepth 20 -name "*.jar" -print | while read line; do
    for i in `jar tf $line | grep .class`
    do
    echo $line : $i
    done 
  done
}
all_hdp_classes > ~/all_hdp_classes
```

Once you have the list, you can search the file as follows:

```
egrep 'kafka' ~/all_hdp_classes | grep Decoder
```

> NB: Ambari only installs the Kafka broker libraries on the node which the Kafka broker is on. So you need to search on that node or you won't find anything (or you will only find the spark-examples).
>   Then copy the Jar onto the node/s which you are running Spark on.

On the Kafka broker node, I found the following Jar which contains the StringDecoder class:

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/libs/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.2.1.2.0-10.jar
```

Note that this is a different file to kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0.jar as suggested in another answer, which did not contain the Decoder class (at least, in my environment).

Also check your scala version for 2.10 or 2.11 and make sure the Jar aligns.

### 2. Adding the Jar to your Spark classpath

Include the Jar in your Spark classpath.

Method depends on if you want to update the classpath for a single session with spark-shell or spark-submit only, or if you want to update the classpath for all Spark sessions (eg using Ambari).

For a session of spark-shell:

```
spark-shell --jars /path/to/jar/on/this/node/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.2.1.2.0-10.jar
```

Note that the spark-streaming-kafka maven dependency mentioned in the Spark documentation can causes an conflict during the import step, as explained later.

You can still go ahead and add it using the --packages option if you need it.

Example (Spark 1.6.2 and scala 2.10, yours may differ):

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.2 --jars kafka_2.10-0.10.1.2.1.2.0-10.jar
```

### 3. Importing into your session

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
```

You may get the following error:

```
error: object serializer is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka
```

There is another kafka package included by the maven package in my above example, and therefore it was imported as part of "org.apache.spark.streaming._"

To resolve, do as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import _root_.kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
```

Comment: Adding _root_. helped

Answer (score 0):

One potential reason to cause this issue is you import 

`import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`

before

`import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder`
 .

The correct order is 

`import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder //first
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`